# Nothing returned when I try to scrape mlb.com transactions using rvest

Tags: r, function, dataframe, web-scraping, rvest

I've been trying to scrape the mlb transactions page (http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/transactions/index.jsp#month=5&year=2019) for the corresponding date and text of every given transaction with no luck. Using rvest and the selector gadget I wrote a brief function which should give me the table displayed all the way back from the first available n 2001 to March 2019.

I just get this series of errors and nothing at all happens.

Here is my code to scrape the data from the given website.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)


# breaking the URL into the start and end for easy pasting to fit timespan
url_start = "http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/transactions/index.jsp#month="
url_end = "&year="

# function which scrapes data

mlb_transactions = function(month, year){

  url = paste0(url_start, month, url_end, year)

  payload = read_html(url) %>%
              html_nodes("td") %>%
                html_table() %>%
                  as.data.frame()

  payload

}

# function run on appropriate dates

mlb_transactions(month = 1:12, year = 2001:2019)
```

here are the errors I'm getting

```
 Show Traceback

 Rerun with Debug
 Error in doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) : 
  Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=19].
```

and here is the Traceback

```
12.
stop(structure(list(message = "Expecting a single string value: [type=character; extent=19].", 
    call = doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, 
        options = options), cppstack = NULL), class = c("Rcpp::not_compatible", 
"C++Error", "error", "condition"))) 
11.
doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html, options = options) 
10.
read_xml.character(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, 
    options = options) 
9.
read_xml(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, options = options) 
8.
withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = function(w) invokeRestart("muffleWarning")) 
7.
suppressWarnings(read_xml(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, 
    options = options)) 
6.
read_html.default(url) 
5.
read_html(url) 
4.
eval(lhs, parent, parent) 
3.
eval(lhs, parent, parent) 
2.
read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("td") %>% html_table() %>% as.data.frame() 
1.
mlb_transactions(month = 1:12, year = 2001:2019)
```

One final note is that my plan is, though I don't yet know how to do this, because on the transaction tables not every transaction has a date its direct left but there is an implied date span could I make it so once loaded every empty date column is filled with the info of the column directly above it if filled and this runs a sort of loop or is there a better way to load the dates from the very start?

Comment: You have a couple of issues here.  Calling your function with two vectors is not a nested loop.  Add 'print(url)' in your function to see the result.  Also `read_html()` is design to accept a singe url and not a vector of URLs.

Comment: @Dave2e would I have to modify it to a for loop? like for (year in 2001:2019)..etc?

Comment: Yes, that is a straight forward way.  I would also suggest reading the terms of service on the website to make sure you are not in violation.  Also, I would add a 1 sec pause in between the calls to `read_html` so not to act like a denial of service attack.

Answer (score 2):

**Pseudo code (language agnostic):**

There is an alternative url construct that returns json via a querystring. The querystring has a start and end date.

http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.transaction_all.bam?start_date=20010101&end_date=20031231&sport_code=%27mlb%27

From testing with Python (so R mileage may vary - I will look to add an R example hopefully later) you can issue requests for *2 years at a time and get a json response with the rows of data in. <sub>*This was the more reliable time frame.</sub>

You could construct this in a loop from 2001 to 2018 with a step of 2 i.e.

intervals of

```
['2001-2003', '2004-2006', '2007-2009' ,'2010-2012', '2013-2015', '2016-2018]
```

Then parse the json response for the data of interest. Example json response [here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=b1525cefb5674621b9499163f849760f).

Example row within json:

```
{"trans_date_cd":"D","from_team_id":"","orig_asset":"Player","final_asset_type":"","player":"Rafael Roque","resolution_cd":"FIN","final_asset":"","name_display_first_last":"Rafael Roque","type_cd":"REL","name_sort":"ROQUE, RAFAEL","resolution_date":"2001-03-14T00:00:00","conditional_sw":"","team":"Milwaukee Brewers","type":"Released","name_display_last_first":"Roque, Rafael","transaction_id":"94126","trans_date":"2001-03-14T00:00:00","effective_date":"2001-03-14T00:00:00","player_id":"136305","orig_asset_type":"PL","from_team":"","team_id":"158","note":"Milwaukee Brewers released LHP Rafael Roque."}
```

---

**Note:**

Non-bulk use of the Materials is permitted but bulk usage requires prior consent.

---

**Python example:**

```
import requests

for year in range(2001, 2018, 2):       
    r = requests.get('http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.transaction_all.bam?start_date={0}0101&end_date={1}1231&sport_code=%27mlb%27'.format(year,year + 1)).json()
    print(len(r['transaction_all']['queryResults']['row'])) # just to demonstrate response content
```

This

```
len(r['transaction_all']['queryResults']['row'])
```

gives the number of rows/transactions of data per request (2 year period)

This yields transaction counts of:

```
[163, 153, 277, 306, 16362, 19986, 20960, 23352, 24732]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an `R` alternative - similar to @QHarr's solution. The following function `get_data` takes `year` as argument and fetches the data for `year;year+1` as start and end dates

```
get_data <- function (year) {
  root_url <- 'http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com'
  params_dates <- sprintf('start_date=%s0101&end_date=%s1231', year, year+1)
  params <- paste('/json/named.transaction_all.bam?&sport_code=%27mlb%27', params_dates, sep = '&')
  js <- jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0(root_url, params))
  return (js)
}
get_processed_data <- function (year) get_data(year=year)$transaction_all$queryResults$row
```

The output `js` is of class `list` and the data is stored in `$transaction_all$queryResults$row`.

Finally, the same loop as in the other solution printing out the number of rows of the ouput

```
for (year in seq(2001, 2018, 2)) print(nrow(get_data(year)$transaction_all$queryResults$row))
# [1] 163
# [1] 153
# [1] 277
# [1] 306
# [1] 16362
# [1] 19986
# [1] 20960
# [1] 23352
# [1] 24732
```

Comment: @niko Thanks a tonne. That looks to like it collects the appropriate data but how do I convert that specific section into a dataframe respectful of the columns, something like my following code gives me a one column dataframe which looks odd and has a couple of gaps, etc: ```df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(test)))```

Comment: @8bit See the edit (added the function `get_processed_data`). You can try `df <- get_processed_data(2009)`. About your test: you unlist a list (`test`) which contains the data frame already (`test$transaction_all$queryResults$row`) which becomes a vector. Then you turn it into a matrix but since you do not specify `ncol` it assumes there is only one column. Regardless, using `unlist` is a bad idea since the data is already properly stored and `unlist` will deprive it of any structure.